# redirect url in javascript

Tags: javascript, href, window.location

I have the autocomplete code developed using devbridge package

I'm not able to redirect to url

```
 $('#search_box').autocomplete({
                            lookup: arr,
                            onSelect: function (suggestion) {

                              reporturl="localhost:3000/reports/"+suggestion.data;
                              console.log(reporturl);

                              window.location= reporturl;

                            }
                          });

                  },'json');
```

I'm unable to redirect,why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url either needs to be relative (e.g. '/reports/') or fully qualified with http://

`reporturl="http://localhost:3000/reports/"+suggestion.data;`